# Making a listview from a internal SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am looking to make a `ListView` from a existing database (all the tutorials I have seen create a database in the code though)

I have a internal SQLite database called Favorites and its just containing a list of the user's favorite sports, how can I link the code to that database instead of creating a new one each time and link it to a `Listview`?

Thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean by creating database (that database instead of creating a new one each time) again?

Comment: existing database means what? Did you create a database using `SQLite Browser` and stored it in assets folder and try to access it?

Comment: @Gunaseelan yes, exactly and I want to link it to a listview

Comment: Then see [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/03/sqlite-databases-with-external-db.html) tutorial for accessing data from external db. And [this](http://v4all123.blogspot.com/2013/03/sqlite-database.html) tutorial for load data to listview from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created database in `SQLite Browser` or any other `SQLiteGUI Tool`...

Create a `SQLHELPER` Class in `Your package`.
Just copy paste the below one

Just add your details in the lines

```
 private static String DB_PATH="data/data/com.AZone.egba/databases/";

    //replace it(com.AZone.egba) with your package name

    //Create a folder named "Database" inside assets folder
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="abc.db"; // your database name here
```

rest of the class will remin same

```
package com.AZone.egba.SqlHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.R.string;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.media.JetPlayer.OnJetEventListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_PATH="data/data/com.AZone.egba/databases/";

    //replace it(com.AZone.egba) with your package name

    //Create a folder named "Database" inside assets folder
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="abc.db"; // your database name here
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH_ASSETS="Database"+File.separator;
    private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;



    public SQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,SCHEMA_VERSION);
        this.myContext=context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
        boolean dbExist=checkDatabase();

        if(dbExist){

        }
        else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try{

                copyDataBase();

            }catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error Copying Database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDatabase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB=null;
        try{
            String myPath=DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        if(checkDB!=null){
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB !=null?true:false;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
        InputStream myInput= myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_PATH_ASSETS+DATABASE_NAME);
        String outFileName=DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput=new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer=new byte [1024];
        int length;
        while((length=myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String mypath= DB_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase=SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
     @Override
        public synchronized void close() {

                if(myDataBase != null)
                    myDataBase.close();  
                super.close();

        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }



/////////////////////////////////////////CUSTOM FUNCTIONS/////////////////////////////////////////////  




    public Cursor GetFavouritesList(){

        try
        {
            return(getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id,Name,Code FROM tblfavourites",null));
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
            Log.e("tblfavourites", e.toString());
        }
        return null;

    }


}
```

So as to make it work you have to save your database in assets folder(here I have created further one step down in folder Database)

[image]

Create instance for SQLHelper before `onCreate`

```
SQLHelper helper=null;
```

Then call the below method in  you onCreate() of your activity

```
public void initialazeDatabase()
{
helper=new SQLHelper(this);

        try{
            helper.createDataBase();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable To Create Database");
        }
        try{
             helper.openDataBase();
        }catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
}
```

call

in `onDestroy` of activity

```
helper.close();
```

Now you can access the methods defined in SQLHelper to get the values from database

using `helper.GetFavouritesList()` anywhere

`helper.GetFavouritesList()` will return data in Cursor....

Use `Adapter` to bind the cursor data to `List view`.. (various tutorials are available on net how to bind `listview` with database)

Comment: i have been trying to link the helper.GetFavouritesList() to a cursor to a listview but its not working.... any hints?

Comment: @ZachRyall are you able to access the "helper.GetFavouritesList()" in your desired activity?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create database at every run. Databases are created only once by SQLiteOpenHelper class. So just create a DatabaseAdapter to query database.

EDIT:

Create a class DatabaseAdapter as below:

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
    protected SQLiteDatabase database;  
    public DatabaseAdapter(Context context) {
        MyDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(context, "my_db");
        database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();        
    }

    protected class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name) {
            super(context, name, null, 1);
        } 

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }       
    }

    // Your methods that works with database comes here
}
```

The onCreate method of MyDatabaseHelper class is called only the first time that database is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Hope this can help.

ANd to fill the listview: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

Comment: So how can I link it to a listview?

Comment: You are not the kind of man that search Google ;-) here is the code: http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html